# Python merging rows with conditional logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

New to Python, so please excuse poor articulation.  I have some data in a dataframe that I've applied drop_duplicates to in order to identify state change in an item.  The data is shown below.  My goal is to establish some aging on the Item Id's. (note Created Date is the same on all records for a specific Item Id).
I've edited this to show what I've tried and the result I'm getting.

```
    Item Id      State  Created Date     Date         Severity
0    327863        New   2019-02-11    2019-10-03         1
9    327863   Approved   2019-02-11    2019-12-05         1
12   327863  Committed   2019-02-11    2019-12-26         1
16   327863       Done   2019-02-11    2020-01-23         1
27   327864        New   2019-02-11    2019-10-03         1
33   327864  Committed   2019-02-11    2019-11-14         1
42   327864       Done   2019-02-11    2020-01-16         1
53   341283   Approved   2019-03-11    2019-10-03         1
57   341283       Done   2019-03-11    2019-10-31         1
```

I'm doing the following to merge the rows.

```
s = dfdr.groupby(['Item Id','Created Date', 'Severity']).cumcount()
df1 = dfdr.set_index(['Item Id','Created Date', 'Severity', s]).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)

df1=df1.reset_index()
print(df1[['Item Id', 'Created Date', 'Severity', 'State','Date']])
```

The output looks to me to show what I'm told to avoid, chained indexing.

```
       Item Id            Created Date   Severity      State                                   Date
                                                           0          1          2     3          0          1          2          3
0       194795 2018-09-18 16:11:25.330        3.0        New   Approved  Committed  Done 2019-10-03 2019-10-10 2019-10-17 2019-10-24
1       194808 2018-09-18 16:11:25.330        3.0  Duplicate        NaN        NaN   NaN 2019-10-03        NaT        NaT        NaT
2       270787 2018-11-27 15:55:02.207        1.0        New  Duplicate        NaN   NaN 2019-10-03 2019-10-10        NaT        NaT
```

To use the data in graphing I believe what I want is not the nested data, but rather something like the following, but not sure how to get there.

```
Item Id    Created Date   Severity   New   NewDate      Approved      AppDate   Committed   CommDate   Done   Done Date
123456     3/25/2020         3       New   2019-10-03   Approved   2019-11-05         NaN        NaT   Done  2020-02-17
```

After adding pivot_table and reset_index per Sikan Answer, I'm closer, but I don't get the same output.  This is the output I'm getting.

```
State                                             Approved  Committed       Done  Duplicate        New
Item Id      Created Date            Severity                                                       
194795       2018-09-18              3.0        2019-10-10 2019-10-17 2019-10-24        NaT 2019-10-03
194808       2018-09-18              3.0               NaT        NaT        NaT 2019-10-03        NaT
```

This is specifically my code now

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Excel\DataSample.xlsx')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Item Id', 'State','Created Date'], keep='first')
df['Severity'] = df['Severity'].replace(np.nan,3)
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Item Id', 'Created Date', 'Severity'], columns=['State'], values='Date', aggfunc=lambda x: x)
df.reset_index()
print(df)
```

This is the output

```
State                                     Approved  Committed       Done  Duplicate        New
Item Id      Created Date    Severity                                                       
194795       2018-09-18      3.0        2019-10-10 2019-10-17 2019-10-24        NaT 2019-10-03     
194808       2018-09-18      3.0               NaT        NaT        NaT 2019-10-03        NaT
270787       2018-11-27      1.0               NaT        NaT        NaT 2019-10-10 2019-10-03
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pd.pivot_table for this:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(dfdr, index=['Item Id', 'Created Date', 'Severity'], columns=['State'], values='Date', aggfunc=lambda x: x)
df = df.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    ItemId  CreatedDate     Severity    Approved    Committed   Done        New
0   327863  2019-02-11      1           2019-12-05  2019-12-26  2020-01-23  2019-10-03
1   327864  2019-02-11      1           NaN         2019-11-14  2020-01-16  2019-10-03
2   341283  2019-03-11      1           2019-10-03  NaN         2019-10-31  NaN
```